# Set extra_context data according to login credentials for using in template

Tags: django, authentication, django-views

Well, following th [documentation for login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/) in django site I'm using `django.contrib.auth.views.login` view in urls.py like this:

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',{'template_name': 'login.html'},name="my_login"),
```

I can pass an `extra_context` to this view, what I want is according to user credentials, in case of success login search some relative data to user for print it in template like name, address, etc... storing in session or something like that, using for example `{{ request.user.username }}` in template I can retrieve the username for the login request, that's what I want but searching some data according to his username in `auth_user`. Can I do that with this view or have I implement for my own?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new view using the login view, in which you pass the `extra_settings`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login as auth_views_login

def login(*args, **kwargs):
    extra_context = {'extra_value': 'some data here'} 
    return auth_views_login(*args, extra_context=extra_context, **kwargs)
```

Then just replace the Django view with yours in urls.py:

```
url(r'^login/$',
    'myapp.views.login',
    {'template_name': 'login.html'},
    name="my_login"),
```